# foreach loop stopping on the first xml element

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML data

```
 <Items>
    <Request>
    <IsValid>True</IsValid>
    <ItemLookupRequest>
    <Condition>All</Condition>
    <IdType>ISBN</IdType>
    <ItemId>0071762345</ItemId>
    <ResponseGroup>AlternateVersions</ResponseGroup>
    <SearchIndex>All</SearchIndex>
    <VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
    </ItemLookupRequest>
    </Request>
    <Item>
    <ASIN>0071762345</ASIN>
    <AlternateVersions>
    <AlternateVersion>
    <ASIN>B0058O8V9U</ASIN>
    <Title>
    Likeable Social Media: How to Delight Your Customers, Create an Irresistible Brand, and Be Generally Amazing on Facebook (& Other Social Networks) [Paperback] Dave Kerpen Dave Kerpen
    </Title>
    <Binding>Unknown Binding</Binding>
    </AlternateVersion>
    <AlternateVersion>
    <ASIN>B00511ONPG</ASIN>
    <Title>
    Likeable Social Media: How to Delight Your Customers, Create an Irresistible Brand, and Be Generally Amazing on Facebook (& Other Social Networks)
    </Title>
    <Binding>Kindle Edition</Binding>
    </AlternateVersion>
    <AlternateVersion>
    <ASIN>0071813721</ASIN>
    <Title>
    Likeable Social Media: How to Delight Your Customers, Create an Irresistible Brand, and Be Generally Amazing on Facebook (& Other Social Networks)
    </Title>
    <Binding>Hardcover</Binding>
    </AlternateVersion>
    </AlternateVersions>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <ASIN>B00511ONPG</ASIN>
    <AlternateVersions>
    <AlternateVersion>
    <ASIN>0071762345</ASIN>
    <Title>
    Likeable Social Media: How to Delight Your Customers, Create an Irresistible Brand, and Be Generally Amazing on Facebook (And Other Social Networks)
    </Title>
    <Binding>Paperback</Binding>
    </AlternateVersion>
    <AlternateVersion>
    <ASIN>B0058O8V9U</ASIN>
    <Title>
    Likeable Social Media: How to Delight Your Customers, Create an Irresistible Brand, and Be Generally Amazing on Facebook (& Other Social Networks) [Paperback] Dave Kerpen Dave Kerpen
    </Title>
    <Binding>Unknown Binding</Binding>
    </AlternateVersion>
    <AlternateVersion>
    <ASIN>0071813721</ASIN>
    <Title>
    Likeable Social Media: How to Delight Your Customers, Create an Irresistible Brand, and Be Generally Amazing on Facebook (& Other Social Networks)
    </Title>
    <Binding>Hardcover</Binding>
    </AlternateVersion>
    </AlternateVersions>
    </Item>
    </Items>
    </ItemLookupResponse>
```

and I am using the code to search each Binding element and then do stuff with it like this

```
foreach($xml->Items->Item->AlternateVersions->AlternateVersion->Binding as $BookBinding) { //loop through the xml data to find the correct ASIN for the kindle edition
    foreach ($xml->Items->Item->AlternateVersions->AlternateVersion->ASIN as $Kindlestring)
    {
        var_dump ($BookBinding);
        if (preg_match('/Kindle Edition/i',$BookBinding))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

but getting only the first iteration of $Binding and $ASIN instead of all the 4 elements
the output from var_dump is "Unknown Binding" & B0058O8V9U

Comment: It looks like you have some invalid XML there. Try running it through http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp and correct the relevant errors before trying again.

Comment: That is not a *but*, that is just correct. Different to an xpath query, the iteators you use here "contain" only a single element each.  You might want to use an xpath query liek `/*/*/Item/*/AlternateVersion/Binding` and the like instead.

Comment: to get the ASINs of all Items with Kindle Edition Bindings use `//ASIN[following-sibling::Binding = "Kindle Edition"]`

Comment: Please do not delete your content in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
foreach($xml->Items->Item as $item){
    foreach($item->AlternateVersions->AlternateVersion as $alt_version){
        var_dump($alt_version->Binding);
        var_dump($alt_version->ASIN);
        ...
    }
}
```

First iterate throught 'item' and then 'AlternateVersion'.